# What is the difference between difference values of attribute showAsAction in item element in menus android?

Tags: android, menu

What is the difference between the following in menus in android as I am getting the same output as when using never when using any of these:

1.withText
2.collapsActionView

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

You have the answer on Google Developer site [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

withText for example, you can use in form android:showAsAction="always|withText" and it will try to show always text along with icon if there is room for it.

collapseActionView for example, you can use in form android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" to only show that item when menu is in collapsed view.

withText

> Also include the title text (defined by android:title) with the action >item. You can include this value along with one of the others as a flag >set, by separating them with a pipe |.

collapseActionView

> The action view associated with this action item (as declared by android:actionLayout or android:actionViewClass) is collapsible.
>   Introduced in API Level 14.

Answer (score 0):

There are five values associated with showAsAction. There differences are below.

- **ifRoom** - only place an item in the app bar if there is room. If there are multiple items with "ifRoom" flag a few will be shown as actions in the app bar and the rest will be visible in an overflow menu.
- **withText** - shows text defined in the title for the item without an icon. You can add one more flag using pipe "|". eg- "always|withText".
- **never**- It will always show the item in the overflow menu instead of the app bar.
- **always**- It will always show the item in the app bar. Avoid using this because if there are multiple items with the same flag it will overlap with other UI in the appbar.
- **collapseActionView**- The action view associated with this action item (as declared by android:actionLayout or android:actionViewClass) is collapsible.
  Introduced in API Level 14.
- For more info visit [menu-resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource)